# need to wait for MarkerWithLabel to finish populating the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-binding

I'm using MarkerWithLabel (excellent little tool by the way) to mark several dozen locations on a map - in this case ~300.

So I loop through the elements of my data and on each iteration of the loop, create a label like so

```
int i = 1;
for(b in data){

var figureLabel = document.createElement("FIGURE");
var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
pictureLabel.src = "Assets/my_icon.png";

var caption = document.createElement("FIGCAPTION");
var text = document.createTextNode(i);

caption.appendChild(text);
figureLabel.appendChild(pictureLabel);
figureLabel.appendChild(caption);

markers[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position : new google.maps.LatLng(data[b].latitude, data[b].longitude),
       map : map,
       labelContent : figureLabel,
       labelClass : "labels",
       labelAnchor : new google.maps.Point(33.5, 56)
    });
    i++;
}
console.log('Map is populated!');
```

I'm here writing a question though, so let's not get too excited, there's a problem.  Once all of these guys are loaded onto the map, I need to bind a `click` event to each of these markers.  Let's say it will look like this:

```
$('figure').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('figcaption').text());
});
```

It should be as simple as allowing the `for:in` loop to complete, but there's a pretty obvious lag between the completion of the loop and the placement of the labels.  The log 'Map is populated!` happens several hundred milliseconds before the markers appear, and indeed if I bind my events right after the loop is complete, it will fail to find anything to bind to, and I don't get the desired functionality.

So what I've tried is to attach a listener to my map object like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    //Bind some click events    
});
```

And this actually works *sometimes* but is completely unreliable.  I've also tried other listeners like `boundschanged` and `idle` but these are also unreliable.

So I need some way to identify the point in my control flow where the markers and their respective DOM elements are actually appended to the map, not simply when the loop which contains their instantiation completes.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try attaching the listener directly to the marker object with `google.maps.event.addListener()`. [See here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#removing) for a direct example (and more) on both adding and removing listeners to markers.

To not rely on links alone, the relevant example from there including both addition and (one method for the) removal of listeners is

```
var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', aFunction);
google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
```

Of course, you were already using this function in your example code, just not applied to the markers themselves.

The MarkerWithLabel docs also contain [lots of examples](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html), including ones dealing with events, that you may have missed.

Comment: It took some tinkering, attaching the listener was being rather cantankerous since I have my markers in an array, but I got it working.  I had tried to use this before, but I couldn't get it to work because I got stuck on the idea of binding the events with jQuery.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be getting caught on the last element.  That is to say binding a click to markers[i] results in all marker clicks being bound to markers[final_element], even though each markers[] is a seperate object as shown on the map.

Comment: You should show your updated code if you need more help with it.